# Recursive queries in Google Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have tried to implement recursive queries using [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) and [CONNECT BY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) statements with no luck.
Is it possible to implement recursive queries in Google Spanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no support for this right now.